# how to run jquery code after hml form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#saveBtn').click(function(){
            var prenom_length = $('#form_prenom').val().length;
            if (prenom_length<5) {
                $('#prenom_error').html("please enter an other name");
            }
           });   

       });
</script>
```

the jquery code is working few seconds after form submission the  displays the error text  just before the page reloads but after reloading the page it disappears , i want it to keep the same text even after the page refresh how to do ?

Comment: This question has been answered many times on this site. Search for it.

Comment: You can not move data from current page session to the new session in reloaded page. Unless you want to use something like cookies or client-side databases. You have to reload the page? why you don't do it without reloading page?

Comment: Look into using AJAX

Comment: If you submit a form it is like erasing a whiteboard and starting over. If there is a validation error, why is the form allowed to submit?

Comment: can we see your form ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var prenom_length = $('#form_prenom').val().length;
            if (prenom_length<5) {
             $('#prenom_error').html("please enter an other name");
            }
           });   
         
       });
</script>

Comment: guys how do you advice me to handle form dynamically with jquery ?

Comment: Save the information in `sessionStorage`, then the next page can read it out and display it.

Comment: I think the bigger question is why are you allowing the form to submit, if you know there is an error?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show an error message after someone submits the form so that they know they should correct it. By default if you press a submit button in an HTML form the browser wil send the request to the server and the server will give the user a new page.

You want to prevent that last bit from happening. The browser should execute your jQuery and if you find an error in the form you want to prevent that default submit to the server from happening. As it happens (pun intended) jQuery can do exactly that, check out the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).